# create text box by row & column on a userform vba

Tags: vba, excel

Could any one direct me in right direction for the following code? I want to create a text box at run time by row & column.The following creates only a row & not multiple rows. I want the columns to remain same & just keep increasing rows. Thanks in advance :)

```
    Dim txtB1 As Control
    Dim i
    For i = 0 To 4
    Set txtB1 = UserForm.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    With txtB1
        .Name = "chkDemo" & i
        .Height = 20
        .Width = 50
        .Left = 30 * i * 2
        .Top = 15
        .ControlTipText = "Type of Bug"
        End With
    Next i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `For` loop for each dimension (rows *and* columns).

```
Dim txtB1 As Control
Dim i, jrow

For jrow = 1 To 5
    For i = 0 To 4
        Set txtB1 = UserForm.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtB1
        .Name = "chkDemo" & i
        .Height = 20
        .Width = 50
        .Left = 50 * i + 2
        .Top = 20 * jrow + 15
        .ControlTipText = "Type of Bug"
        End With
    Next i
Next jrow
```

Result:

[image]